# How to create Three.js buttons like this example

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I am creating a web application similar to this Ford mustang customizing page.

http://www.ford.com/cars/mustang/customizer/#!/customize

I'm new to THREE.JS, but Visually I am quite far a long in the projects. Id really like to incorporate something like the interactive buttons in the link example, but don't really know where to start. Has it got something to do with CSS3DRenderer ? or am I completely off track? Hope some one can help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show code and effort. Right now your question is off topic

Comment: It looks like they're doing it will a simple change in css styling on hover. They're toggling different elements visability, opacity, height, and using a transform-matrix. If you inspect it with your browser it should be pretty simple to replicate.